# ASUS ROG GL551J SSD location?

Tags: ssd, laptop-repair, asus-laptop

The SSD in my ASUS ROG GL551J failed today (unfortunately, not under warranty), so I followed the guide on [ASUS's website](http://rog.asus.com/15842014/hands-on/g551-upgrade-guide/) to take the computer apart to see where the SSD is so that I can replace it.

Unfortunately, the guide only shows how to find the HDD and a small mSATA SSD used as a cache.

So, does anyone know where in the device I would find the 128(ish)GB SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "SSD 128GB MSATA HC KINGSTON/RBU-SMSM151S3/128GD" card sits under the bottom cover between the RAM and 3n1 card reader for the ASUS Republic of Gamers (ROG) GL551JW-DS74 laptop. You must remove the 11 bottom cover screws (2 are in the DVD device slot). Then pry off the edges to remove the cover.

[SSD card in ASUS ROG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adfOi.jpg)